# Program to export SVG to print and animation?

Tags: svg, software-recommendation, corel-draw, file-format

I would like to create animated SVG diagrams for use on Web, **as well as** conventional print.  At present I draw my conventional pictures on CorelDraw 12. When it comes to SVG I have no experience, but CorelDraw does export to that format. (Not sure about animations though?)

So, my specific question is this:  Is there a single graphics software program that draws a picture **ONCE**, but which can be exported to two platforms?

1. Static printable diagram such as PDF, WMF.
2. Animated SVG equivalent to the above

Comment: This is like asking ... "I want a GIF that's good for the web AND for print" -- there's no such animal. You create an image then save to various formats for different uses.

Answer (score 1):

WMF is an ugly buggy format. Do not use it for printing. Try to avoid it.

Corel output for print is very good, but you have the risk of not having some profiles updated becouse your version is some years old.

Yes you can draw once, but in any program you choose, you need to draw an image acordingly to the ouput. Correct colors for print or correct colors for web, the amount of nodes, transparencies or grdients, and embeded images.

But for animations... I am not aware of any drawing program to animate them. It can be done via code, normally JavaScript and CSS like this:

https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

http://snapsvg.io/demos/

http://raphaeljs.com/ < What a cute name...

The 2 real progrms you have to draw and print are Ilustrator and Corel, and both can export fairly decent SVG.

For simple SVG Inkscape is very good (but not that good for print).

If you are familiar with Corel I see no reason to change it, probably update it. When I need to export a "more compilant" svg, I draw it on Corel, open it on Inkscape and re-save it. It is a simple step.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator is probably the best tool for creating vector diagrams, both for web and print. It can be used to generate both static and animated SVGs.

Comment: Thanks. Do Corel and Inkscape reasonably compare?

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator does not have the ability to animate anything. You'll be using illustrator for the static parts and than import into after effects